# Clear a TList or a TObjectList

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, tlist

I'm a bit puzzled of what to use for storing objects in a list.
Until now I have used `TList` and freed each item in a loop. Then I discovered `TObjectList` that do this automatically from `Free`. Then I saw this from the doc of `TList.Clear`:

> Call `Clear` to empty the Items array and set the `Count` to 0. `Clear` also
>   frees the memory used to store the `Items` array and sets the `Capacity` to 0.

So it is basically the same. So

for `TList`

```
mylist.Clear;
myList.Free;
```

is the same as for `TObjectList`?

```
myList.Free;
```

Can `TObjectList` only be used for items as classes or can I store records?

Comment: The part you quote is only "basically the same" if you don't read the TObjectList documentation carefully: "If the OwnsObjects property is set to true (the default), TObjectList controls the memory of its objects, freeing an object when its index is reassigned; when it is removed from the list with the Delete, Remove, or Clear method; or when the TObjectList instance is itself destroyed." TList's documentation says nothing about that behavior. That's the fundamental difference between the two classes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**1. TList won't free the elements, with both `Clear` or `Free`.**

aList.Clear;

Will just set `aList.Count := 0` without freeing the `aList.Items[]` elements. So you'll leak memory. You'll need an explicit free as such:

```
for i := 0 to aList.Count-1 do
  TObject(aList[i]).Free;
```

But this is what `TObjectList` does... :)

About `TObjectList`, it is worth saying that `TObjectList.Destroy` is calling `Clear`.

So

```
aObjectList.Clear;
aObjectList.Free;
```

is exactly the same as

```
aObjectList.Free;
```

**2. To store a list of records, you can use a dynamic array.**

You'll get all `TList` methods (and more) with our [dynamic array wrapper](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI). That is, `Add / Delete / Clear / Count / IndexOf / Find`...

It has built-in serialization features (in binary or JSON), automated sorting and comparison (using RTTI) which are not existing with a `TList/TObjectList`. From Delphi 5 and later.

With more modern version of Delphi, you may use *generics* to handle the dynamic array, if you do not want to use a third-party library.

Comment: Just a clearification about `TObjectList`. It has a property: `OwnsObjects` (default = true) which controls if the objects in the list are being freed when items are removed.

Comment: @LURD You are right. This property may be handy, but also misleading: you may suppose that objects will be freed, but if you set `OwnObjects := false` somewhere in the code (even at runtime), you would easily leak memory or resources: so to be used with care! I prefer a clear `TList / TObjectList` separation.

Answer (score 13):

It's not the same `TList.Clear` only frees the memory allocated to store the pointers, not objects they are pointing to.
To avoid memory leaks you need to free the memory yourself - as you have been doing - or use `TObjectList`.

To answer the second question, `TObjectList` doesn't support storing records. You need to use `TList` (or something else) in that case.

Comment: Know managing records in a `TList` requires quite some effort though.

Answer (score 10):

Read what the documentation is saying more carefully:

> Clear also frees **the memory used to store the Items array**

Only the memory for the array itself is freed, not the memory used by individual elements inside the array.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a recent version of Delphi I suggest that you use a generic list.

Right now you probably need to do a lot of casting when you use the objects from the list. With a generic list you don't have to do that anymore.

For instance if you have:

```
TMyObject = class(TObject);
```

Then you make the list like this:

```
TMyObjectList = TObjectList<TMyObject>;
```

There is an article in the Embarcadero Wiki:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE8/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_(Delphi)

Answer (score 0):

Really watching the `TObjectList` code in contnrs.pas `OwnObjects` does nothing. `FOwnObjects` is a variable declared in the private part of `TObjectList` that is not used anywhere in the `TObjectList` code (except just assigning the value), and there is no overridden `Clear` procedure in it.

So I'm afraid it necessary to free the memory just the same as in `TList`.

Comment: The property `TObjectList.OwnsObjects` is true by default. You can change the property value after creation. If this property is true when calling `TObjectList.Free`, all objects in the list will be deallocated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastian Zartner: look at "TObjectList.Notify" - there you can see, that it calls "Free" for the items in case "OwnsObjects" is set:

```
procedure TObjectList.Notify(Ptr: Pointer; Action: TListNotification);
begin
  if OwnsObjects then
    if Action = lnDeleted then
      TObject(Ptr).Free;
  inherited Notify(Ptr, Action);
end
```