# Reference counted TList<T> vs TObjectList<T>

Tags: delphi, generics, containers

Can anyone point me toward tutorials or best practice for using object interfaces in a TList?

I started implementing this model to take advantage of the reference counting as an alternative to TObjectList (that I use extensively). While I had no problems implementing the list it appears that doing this adds complexity in other ways.

Specifically because the list is only holding an interface I don't have access to the class fields (obvious). So I end up littering the code with "MyInterface as TMyClass" or creating a lot of functions to access the fields. Is there some trick that I am not aware of that makes an interface container more usable?

Comment: Extend your interfaces to support everything you need. Or, if you don't want to do that, and there are often very good reasons not to, use classes.

Comment: If you have to write `MyInterface as TMyClass` it smells that you broke the abstraction principle of interfaces, and also most of the SOLID principles. And putting interfaces into a list is also often unsafe, because it opens the door to interface circular references and  therefore leaking instances.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TInterfaceList ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access certain methods, why are you hiding them with interfaces? An interface is just that: A description of the ways that others can interact [*interface*] with that object: If you want other classes to interact with your class as an interfaced object, those methods should be part of the interface.

Using an interface as a shortcut to simplify finalization and then hacking it with casting violates the entire concept of interfaces, and can also cause memory leaks and hard to track down AV's, because of the way you are mixing your references: sometimes interface, sometimes TObject.

> Can anyone point me toward tutorials or best practice for using object
>   interfaces in a TList?

Your problem has nothing to do with TList. All TList does is hold references to your objects, however they are designed - it knows nothing about the specifics of your object's interface or implementation. Your problem is that you are not designing your classes and interfaces correctly, as @ArnaudBouchez has pointed out in the comments.

---

> I started implementing this model to take advantage of the reference
>   counting as an alternative to TObjectList (that I use extensively)

Why is that necessary? To simplify finalization? TObjectList owns its objects by default. (And you can also set the `OwnsObjects` property ) . You don't need to use interfaces to automate your clean-up if you're using TObjectList. You just have to free the TObjectList instance, just as you have to free a TList. Unless you need interfaces for a specific reason, using Objects and TObjectList is arguably preferable, since as opposed to interfaces, your finalization is deterministic.

From XE Help:

> Create TObjectList instance.
>
> This overloaded method creates a TObjectList instance.
>
> **The OwnsObjects parameter is a boolean that indicates whether object
>   entries are owned by the list. If the object is owned, when the entry
>   is removed from the list, the object is freed. The OwnsObjects
>   property is set from the value of this parameter. The default is true.**

When you free TObjectList, the objects are also deallocated when `OwnObjects=True`. 
See:
[***Clear a TList or a TObjectList (accepted answer there)***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410019/clear-a-tlist-or-a-tobjectlist)

**Know**: Normally there is no reason for you as a Delphi developer to get involved at all with details of reference counting. If you feel you need to do so, something is wrong with your design at the fundamental level. Reference counting is implemented in TInterfacedObject, and works transparently. All of your Delphi interfaced objects should be derived from TInterfacedObject (or one of its sibling or derivative classes), as follows:

```
interface
...

type

IMyInterface=interface (IUnknown)
[GUID]
 function GetValue:integer;
end;

TMyInterface=class(TInterfacedObject,IMyInterface)
 protected
   function GetValue:integer;
end;

implementation
...


TMyInterface.GetValue:integer;
begin
  result := fValue;
end;

end.
```

Then use it like this:

```
procedure useValue;
var im:IMyInterface;
    x:integer;
begin
 im:=TMyInterface.create;
 x:=im.GetValue;
 showMessage(inttstr(x));
end;
```

When `useValue` returns, `im` is cleaned up - you don't have to do anything or worry about reference counting. `TInterfacedObject` takes care of all that.

---

*Note that in `useValue`, you declare the reference as IMyInterface but call the class constructor for `TMyInterface` - that is how you must initialize the interface - an interface has no constructor. However, since your reference type is `IMyInterface`, that is how it is treated by the compiler - only methods exposed through `IMyInterface` will be accessible*.

Comment: You are correct that I was thinking that the reference counting feature of interfaces could make it easier to manage the objects but what you say makes perfect sense. I am trying to make myself use interfaces more (as it appears to be recommended practice) as an old OO developer its hard to learn new tricks. I was also very interested in the [weak] interface pointer as a way for references to items on a list automatically null themselves when the item was deleted but in reflection the need for it is probably bad design on my part.

Comment: _I am trying to make myself use interfaces more (as it appears to be recommended practice_ - Don't do something just because its 'recommended practice' - do it because you have a problem that you can solve better, or an improvement you can implement when using the 'recommended practice'. Interfaces are good for some things, but not always. ObjectLists, Protected Singletons and Class Methods are often better solutions. Using Class Methods and a functional programming approach, you may discover that 50% of your objects don't need to be initialized at all.